# Method named `start()` executes without calling at object initialization

Tags: php

I'm writing `cli` app, so I created main class with few methods, one of them is named `start()`. To simplify:

```
class Foo{

   ...

   public function start(){
      echo "Let's start!";
      ...
   }

}
```

To run my app, I instantiate new object of `Foo` class and call `start()` method:

```
class Foo{
   ...
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->start();
```

What have I noticed is that `start()` is executed on object construction, even if there is no `__construct()` method in `Foo` class. That's weird.

Output from terminal:

```
$ php start.php
Let's start!
Let's start!
```

Does `start()` stands for one of PHP's magic methods? I'm on PHP 5.5.

Comment: Do you have a method named "Foo"? I was unable to reproduce this on PHP 5.4.

Comment: Initially class was named `Start`, as well as method that I'm asking about. I've changed that in listings for more readable code. Do you suggest that it has something to do with: if class name == method name, then that method is called as constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In legacy PHP 4, the constructor wasn't named `__construct`, but was the name of the class. E.g.:

```
class Start {

    function start() {
        // I am the constructor
    }

}
```

PHP 5 still supports this legacy behaviour, looking for a method of the same name as the class if no constructor is present.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: You beat me to it deceze! As soon as I saw the OP's comment I was about to answer, but then "1 new answer to this question" popped up.